# Accessing the await-ed value inline (JS)?

Tags: javascript, async-await

First I wrote something like this:

```
(async function() {
    const value = await Promise.resolve({a: 3}).a
    console.log(value)
})().catch(console.error);
```

But I quickly came to the conclusion that that's not going to work since we're gonna be awaiting the `a` property of what `Promise.resolve` returns, which is undefined.

So I tried to wrap my `await` call into parenthesis:

```
(async function() {
    const value = await(Promise.resolve({a: 3})).a
    console.log(value)
})().catch(console.error);
```

Which didn't work either. (it logs `undefined`)

So it seems the only way to extract the `a` prop is to do something like this:

```
(async function() {
    const resolvedValue = await Promise.resolve({a: 3});
    let aProp = resolvedValue['a']; 
})().catch(console.error);
```

, which adds an unnecessary line of code.

I feed like this kinda defeats the purpose of async/await. Is this correct or am I missing something?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to wrap the `await` keyword and the promise in parentheses, like that:

```
const value = (await Promise.resolve({a: 3})).a;
```

This way you're awaiting the promise and then accessing the `a` property of the resolved value.

`await(Promise.resolve({a: 3})).a` doesn't work, because `await` is not a function, but an operator.

Comment: I run the code in node and chrome, both show "SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" ?

Comment: Can anyone provide a link to some documentation or additional explanation of this syntax?

Answer (score 4):

you need to `await` on a promise, not a property of one. JavaScript is going to expect `a` to be a promise, but its not.

`await` is an operator statement, not a function.

Comment: That's what I tried to do with parenthesis in my 2nd block of code.

Comment: @BogdanM. `await` is a statement, not a function.

Comment: Whoops. I thought that it'd be valid. (probably because you can also wrap statements such as `throw` into parenthesis). Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

you can always destructure:

```
const { a: value } = await Promise.resolve({ a: 3})
```