# Puppeteer - page.$$('').length returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, puppeteer

I was having errors with my code, so i tried to log the value in the erroneous code. So i did:

```
const read = await page.$$('.Ns6lhs9 _gfh3').length;
```

Then i `console.log(read);`

For some reason i get `undefined` although there are elements with class name `'Ns6lhs9 _gfh3'` in the HTML

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing the await-ed value inline (JS)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40893232/accessing-the-await-ed-value-inline-js)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$$` returns a promise of an element, while `length` is not a promise, it's actual value.

It should be:

```
const read = (await page.$$('.Ns6lhs9._gfh3')).length;
```

Comment: Thanks! But now for some reason it returns 0, while there are these elements with that class name in the HTML...

Comment: Well, this depends on your case. Notice that the selector looks for `_gfh3` *element*, not class or else, and it is very unlikely that it should be so.

Comment: What i wanted to do was select elements with attribute : <div class="Ns6lhs9 _gfh3">

Comment: It's `.Ns6lhs9._gfh3` then. It's a class.

Comment: shouldnt you edit this to be`(await page.$$('.Ns6lhs9._gfh3')).length;`

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar issue with getting 0 when counting elements using CSS selector. I tried xpath selector instead and for some reason it did work.

Comment: What exactly do you mean xpath selector?