# How to use length property with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, puppeteer, jsdom

EDIT: I solved my problem. I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50704495/puppeteer-page-length-returns-undefined).

I am trying to create an automation program using Puppeteer, node.js and jquery.

I want to go to a page on reddit and count the number of h2 tags that have a class of '**s1okktje-0**'. Whenever I run the program, it always outputs 0, even though it should output 25. Why is it not working?

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function count () {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ 
        headless: false,
        args:
        [
            '--disable-notifications',
        ]
    });

    function delaySeconds(timeout) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            setTimeout(() => { resolve(timeout) }, timeout * 1000);
        });
    }

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://www.reddit.com/user/warnakey/', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
    await page.waitForSelector('button.pqvesn-2.kOkfJW');
    await page.addScriptTag({url: 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js'})

    await delaySeconds(15);

    let numItems = (await page.$$('h2.s1okktje-0')).length;
    console.log("The number of items with class 's1okktje-0' is " + numItems);
    console.log("The number above should be 25");

    await browser.close()
}

count()
```

Comment: is that class belonging to h2 tag or child of h2 tag

Comment: @VeshrajJoshi - it belongs to h2. It is not a child of h2. It looks like this: <h2 class="s1okktje-0 kCqBrs">I finally beat Dark Souls!</h2>

Comment: If they aren't there when that code runs then good chance they are inserted asynchronously after page loads. Add a timeout delay. Note that the question is not really clear what the structure actually is and should be updated. The term *"contains"* is misleading as it typically indicates a descendant

Comment: @charlietfl I added a 30 second delay (and updated my code above). It still did not work.